# mapping array in associative

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array defined.

```
$a = Array
(
    [0] => 30:27
    [1] => 29:28
    [2] => 30:27
)
$b = Array
(
    [0] => 102186
    [3] => 102991
    [4] => 102241
)
```

I have used `array_map($a,$b);` But not what i want the result comes.

Always first to first key, second to second key, third to third key, I expect the following result...

```
$ab = $b = Array
    (
        [0] => 102186 [30:27]
        [1] => 102991 [29:28]
        [2] => 102241 [30:27]
    )
```

Comment: So you want to merge the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the 1st array and add the corresponding value from the 2nd one.  You can actually use `array_map` for this:

```
$ab = array_map(function($aVal, $bVal){
    return "$bVal [$aVal]";
}, $a, $b);
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/78684

Comment: Thanks you answer is perfect to me.

Answer (score 3):

### Edit:

If the array keys doesn't match (thought it was a typo), then just reset the arrays by using `$a = array_values($a)` and `$b = array_values($b)` like this:

```
$a = array(
    0 => "30:27",
    1 => "29:28",
    2 => "30:27"
);
$b = array(
    0 => "102186",
    3 => "102991",
    4 => "102241"
);

// Reset keys
$a = array_values($a);
$b = array_values($b);

$ab = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    $ab[] = "{$b[$i]} [{$a[$i]}]";
}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ab);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 102186 [30:27]
    [1] => 102991 [29:28]
    [2] => 102241 [30:27]
)
```

Comment: That is nice too, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**USE:**

$arrayFirst and $arraySecond - your input arrays;

```
   $result = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayFirst); $i++) {
        $result[] = "{$arraySecond[$i]} [{$arrayFirst[$i]}]";
    }

    var_dump ($result);
```

**Or [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)**

```
$array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: This doesn't give the result that he's looking for.  Plus your 2nd example doesn't even work.  `$value` isn't an array.

Comment: Eh, made a mistake. Edited.

Comment: Thanks,I have made a mistake. Edited.